# select value from second table which ID is in my first table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to select value from second table which ID is in my first table. I've tried this:

```
    select
    FIRST_NAME,
    LAST_NAME,
    c.name status    
    from STUDENTS
    left join PAYER_STATUS c on Status = c.ID
    where status like N'%'||'active'||'%';!
```

but it displays nothing. Here's just empty everything. But If I'll change *active* to *0* it displays in status column words *active*. for *1* *inactive* etc.

[tables here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDGw4.png)

How can I solve that?

Comment: Please post the create table and insert statements. And show your desired output.

Comment: @LalitKumarB It's created a long time ago and past programmer created it. there should be output active, active, active in Status collumn where Status is 0 (see the picture I've provided)

Comment: is there another status column in the STUDENTS table? Do select * from both tables to get us all column names!

Comment: @jarlh It's too big table (students). and they have nothing similar for this problem. but second table I've selected *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use your column name in where clause. coz you have `status` column present in table. so it will check the passed value with that column instead of c.name

```
select
s.FIRST_NAME,
s.LAST_NAME,
c.name as status    
from STUDENTS s
left join PAYER_STATUS c on s.Status = c.ID
where c.name like N'%'||'active'||'%';!
```

Comment: It doesn't works. maybe query can't recognise id of Status? idk.. P.S. I've not downvoted

Comment: @George try the edited one

Comment: what is your join condition ? is that status from student table and id from payer_status tables is that right ?

Comment: It's funny but my problem was that in db word active is in uppercase and I was trying lowercase. thanks

Comment: glad you found the loop hole

Answer (score 1):

You can't use column aliases in `WHERE`/`ON`, Also, when `LEFT JOIN` move `WHERE` clause conditions for outer table to `ON` clause, else it will be a regular `INNER JOIN`.

```
select FIRST_NAME,
       LAST_NAME,
       c.name status    
from STUDENTS s
  left join PAYER_STATUS c
    on s.somecolumn = c.ID
    and c.name like N'%'||'active'||'%';!
```

Comment: c.name and c.id are in same table ... how can we get join two tables with it ?

Comment: Good question! What do I know, I haven't seen the table def's yet... (I'll edit.)

Comment: It's funny but my problem was that in db word active is in uppercase and I was trying lowercase. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am showing you a **complete test case**, probably **from next time you could provide us** similarly so that it would be easy for us to **reproduce your problem**. So that **we don't have to reverse engineer and build the tables and required data**:

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE status(ID NUMBER, NAME VARCHAR2(20));

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE students(NAME VARCHAR2(10), status VARCHAR2(20));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO status VALUES(0, 'ACTIVE');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO status VALUES(1, 'INACTIVE');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO status VALUES(2, 'SUSPEND');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO students VALUES('a', 0);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO students VALUES('b', 0);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO students VALUES('c', 0);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO students VALUES('d', 1);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

**Tables**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM status;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         0 ACTIVE
         1 INACTIVE
         2 SUSPEND

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM students;

NAME       STATUS
---------- --------------------
a          0
b          0
c          0
d          1

SQL>
```

**Required query:**

```
SQL> SELECT a.NAME,
  2    a.status,
  3    b.NAME
  4  FROM students a
  5  JOIN status b
  6  ON (a.status   = b.ID)
  7  WHERE a.status = 0;

NAME       STATUS               NAME
---------- -------------------- ------
a          0                    ACTIVE
b          0                    ACTIVE
c          0                    ACTIVE

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks. next time I'll try to improve my question. your code doesn't works as well. The main idea there was that it searches when I'll try to search it by A.status (which is 0 in this case). but if I'll change A.status to b.Name and I'll try to search by 'active' it doesn't works

Comment: Then show us the way I have shown. What are your doing, what is your query? What is the desired output? Edit your question, add these details.

Comment: It's funny but my problem was that in db word active is in uppercase and I was trying lowercase. thanks